# How to add custom email to account user emails?

Tags: emails, users

There are a few email templates in account user emails page: "/admin/config/people/accounts".

How can i add custom emails from my own module? I would like to have&edit all email templates in the same place.

Comment: With hook_form_alter, maybe? :)

Comment: i don't think this is the best (or possible) solution ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This form is defined in core user module, [user.admin.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.admin.inc/7) file:

```
/**
 * Form builder; Configure user settings for this site.
 *
 * @ingroup forms
 * @see system_settings_form()
 */
function user_admin_settings() {
```

Particularly, line 444 starts email template section:

```
$form['email'] = array(
    '#type' => 'vertical_tabs',
  );
  // These email tokens are shared for all settings, so just define
  // the list once to help ensure they stay in sync.
  $email_token_help = t('Available variables are: [site:name], [site:url], [user:name], [user:mail], [site:login-url], [site:url-brief], [user:edit-url], [user:one-time-login-url], [user:cancel-url].');

  $form['email_admin_created'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Welcome (new user created by administrator)'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => (variable_get('user_register', USER_REGISTER_VISITORS_ADMINISTRATIVE_APPROVAL) != USER_REGISTER_ADMINISTRATORS_ONLY),
    '#description' => t('Edit the welcome e-mail messages sent to new member accounts created by an administrator.') . ' ' . $email_token_help,
    '#group' => 'email',
  );
  $form['email_admin_created']['user_mail_register_admin_created_subject'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Subject'),
    '#default_value' => _user_mail_text('register_admin_created_subject', NULL, array(), FALSE),
    '#maxlength' => 180,
  );
```

As you can see, there is no `foreach`, no external hook call, nothing. Just raw fields hardcoded. The only way is to add your fields using `hook_form_alter()`. Make sure you also add your validators and submit handler to take care of your new fields, because user module will not do it for you.

Comment: What would you suggest then, for custom email templates with translations?

Comment: @gregab [`language_list('enabled')`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/language_list/7) and `foreach`? Something like that, I think.

Comment: @gregab I know this is a really old post, but I'm trying to do the same thing in D8 and your post is the only one I've found that exactly matches my need. How can I find out what you ended up doing?

Comment: @Mołot "Make sure you also add your validators and submit handler to take care of your new fields" Can you please elaborate and provide more information on this?

Comment: @BlondeSwan this answer is now seven years old. You can't reasonably expect me to still be thinking about the topic ;) If you have a follow up question, please ask it as a question, so people still active in Drupal community can help you.

Comment: @Mołot I have and no one has responded. It sucks that I had to ask the question considering someone already did 7 years ago but the person who answered only gave 1/2 an answer